# xvfb bind to localhost instead of *

Tags: linux, bind, x11, systemd, xvfb

I have an XVFB service running as service and it binds to * instead of localhost. For security purposes, it is not recommended and I can't find a way to bind it to localhost. Does anyone know how to make xvfb to bind to localhost? Thanks

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/xvfb.service
[Unit]
Description=XVFB Server
After=network.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple

Restart=always
RestartSec=10

TimeoutSec=30

User=xvfb
Group=xvfb

ExecStart=/usr/bin/Xvfb -screen 0, 1024x768x16
```

```
# systemctl status xvfb
● xvfb.service - XVFB Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/xvfb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-05-28 18:13:57 UTC; 1min 4s ago
 Main PID: 11395 (Xvfb)
   Memory: 4.3M
   CGroup: /system.slice/xvfb.service
           └─11395 /usr/bin/Xvfb -screen 0, 1024x768x16

May 28 18:13:57 ip-10-73-36-143.ec2.internal Xvfb[11395]: Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
May 28 18:13:57 ip-10-73-36-143.ec2.internal Xvfb[11395]: Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
May 28 18:13:57 ip-10-73-36-143.ec2.internal Xvfb[11395]: Initializing built-in extension RECORD
May 28 18:13:57 ip-10-73-36-143.ec2.internal Xvfb[11395]: Initializing built-in extension DPMS
May 28 18:13:57 ip-10-73-36-143.ec2.internal Xvfb[11395]: Initializing built-in extension Present
May 28 18:13:57 ip-10-73-36-143.ec2.internal Xvfb[11395]: Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
May 28 18:13:57 ip-10-73-36-143.ec2.internal Xvfb[11395]: Initializing built-in extension XVideo
May 28 18:13:57 ip-10-73-36-143.ec2.internal Xvfb[11395]: Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
May 28 18:13:57 ip-10-73-36-143.ec2.internal Xvfb[11395]: Initializing built-in extension SELinux
May 28 18:13:57 ip-10-73-36-143.ec2.internal Xvfb[11395]: Initializing built-in extension GLX
```

```
# lsof -Pi | grep -i 'listen'
Xvfb      11395        xvfb    0u  IPv6 2029253      0t0  TCP *:6000 (LISTEN)
Xvfb      11395        xvfb    1u  IPv4 2029254      0t0  TCP *:6000 (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

The safest solution is to just close all the ports like this:

```
Xvfb :0 -nolisten tcp
```

Comment: so the config should be like this: `ExecStart=/usr/bin/Xvfb :0 -nolisten tcp -screen 0, 1024x768x16` ?

Comment: @NamNguyen Maybe like this: ExecStart='/usr/bin/Xvfb :0 -nolisten tcp -screen 0, 1024x768x16' just in case. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: the option -nolisten tcp will not open port but what I want is to open the port 6000 but instead of `*:6000`, I would like `127.0.01:6000` or `localhost:6000`

Comment: Did you export the display to X11? 
export DISPLAY=localhost:1.0

Comment: ```<root@development-use1-unifiedcheckout-services-03f519d41f79eab86></etc/systemd/system>
# echo $DISPLAY
localhost:1.0

<root@development-use1-unifiedcheckout-services-03f519d41f79eab86></etc/systemd/system>
# /usr/bin/Xvfb -screen 0, 1024x768x16``` ```# lsof -Pi | grep -i xvfb
Xvfb      11754        root    0u  IPv6 2071123      0t0  TCP *:6000 (LISTEN)
Xvfb      11754        root    1u  IPv4 2071124      0t0  TCP *:6000 (LISTEN)``` I did export display but still seeing `*:6000`

Comment: @NamNguyen Try this: ExecStart=/usr/bin/Xvfb -listen tcp -screen 0, 1024x768x16

Comment: `-listen` is not a valid option :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214859/discussion-between-bhristov-and-nam-nguyen).